# Concat 3 videos, setting the output frame-rate based on one of the three videos

Tags: ffmpeg, ffprobe

I have 3 videos that I would like to concat. An intro, a main video and an outro. All mp4s, all the same spec except the main video is a different frame rate to the other two video assets.

I am trying to use ffprobe to find out the frame rate of the main video and then apply that frame rate to the output file.

This is what I have so far, but it is not working.

```
#!/bin/bash

mezzfile=mezzfile.mp4
tailtime=20
duration=$(ffprobe -v error -show_entries format=duration -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 $mezzfile)
framerate=$(ffprobe -v 0 -of compact=p=0 -select_streams 0 \
-show_entries stream=r_frame_rate '$mezzfile')

ffmpeg -hide_banner -y \
  -i sting.mp4 \
  -i $mezzfile \
  -i endboard.mp4 \
  -filter_complex \
    "[0:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,fps=${framerate}[v_intro]; \
     [0:a]asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS,fps=${framerate}[a_intro]; \
     [1:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,split[v_main1][v_main2]; \
     [1:a]asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a_main]; \
     [2:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,fps=${framerate}[v_endboard]; \
     [v_main1]select='gt(t,$duration-$tailtime)',scale=w=iw/2:h=ih/2,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v_tail]; \
     [v_endboard][v_tail]overlay[v_pip]; \
     [v_main2]select='lte(t,$duration-$tailtime)',setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v_mid]; \
     [v_intro][v_mid][v_pip]concat=n=3:v=1:a=0[v_out]; \
     [a_intro][a_main]concat=n=2:v=0:a=1[a_out]" \
  -map "[v_out]" \
  -map "[a_out]" \
  output.mp4
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Cheers!

I have tried the code above. Hoping someone can help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: *it is not working* --> what does that mean?

Comment: I was hoping that if I ffprobed the file to get the frame rate, I would then be able to use that tag ($framerate) at the end of the code to set that frame rate for the output videos. This is not working.

Comment: change fps before concat: `[0:v]fps=${framerate}[v_intro];`

Comment: Thank you for your help. I edit the code above with the changes you suggested and am getting the following error...

`[Parsed_asetpts_2 @ 0x1588108c0] Media type mismatch between the 'Parsed_asetpts_2' filter output pad 0 (audio) and the 'Parsed_fps_3' filter input pad 0 (video)
[AVFilterGraph @ 0x156e16dc0] Cannot create the link asetpts:0 -> fps:0
Error initializing complex filters.
Invalid argument`

Comment: Unfortunately I am still struggling with this. Is anyone able to offer any assistance please? Many thanks!